# function and array in c program using pointer

Tags: c, dev-c++

i have program code but the output it's right.

the output should :

```
1 2
3 4
```

the input is :

```
1 2 3 4
```

this my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define size 100

int array2d(int *x[size][size],int a,int b){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<a;i++){
        for(j=0;j<b;j++){
            printf("%d ", x[i][j]); x[i][j]++;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
int main(){
    int a,b;
    int x[size][size];
    
    printf("enter the size of array (row) & (column) : ");
    scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
    
    printf("enter the number : ");
    scanf("%d",&x[size][size]);
    
    array2d(x,a,b);
    
    return 0;
}
```

my code showing output :

```
0 0
0 0
```

what should i do to fixed it? and maybe anybody want to help me to fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not reading the elements from the console properly. The way you read input is wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define size 100

int array2d(int x[size][size], int a, int b)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < b; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", x[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
int main()
{
    int a, b;
    int x[size][size];

    printf("enter the size of array (row) & (column) : ");
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);

    printf("enter the number : ");

    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) //reading input
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &x[i][j]);
        }
    }

    array2d(x, a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

The output :

```
enter the size of array (row) & (column) : 2 2
enter the number : 1 2 3 4
1 2 
3 4
```

Comment: what should i do to input a pointer there? @Krishna